# Не открывается аудиофайл(.mp3) в телеграмм боте на python

Tags: telegram-bot, mp3

Изучаю python несколько дней, решил сделать телеграмм бота про одного из муз. личностей. Но чтобы познакомить человека с его творчеством нужно скинуть его работу в виде аудиофайла. Делаю все как на сайте *pypi.org*, но энивей ничего не получается, даже текст из **else** не выводится.

````
bot = telebot.TeleBot('5102535689:AAHjhBl6Eln3vg2YftppPgB14B4OaTzB15k')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Приветствую тебя путник в моём чертоге.", parse_mode='html')

@bot.message_handler()
def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text == "Альбом":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Stormheit(Demo 1994) \nTo Kampf(Demo 1995) \nVarg Fjerne a Tornet(1995) \nРдяндалир(1996) \nKveldulv(1996) \n(Av) Winterkald(1997) \nЖизнеотрицанью жизневероломство(1998) \nХмель мизантропии(1998) \nХладавзор(1999) \nСтрун натянутых вдохновенья сталь(2000) \nРаздувая тинг ветров(2000) \nТингов наслаждаясь распрей(2000) \nТриумф Воли(2001)" , parse_mode='html')
    elif message.text == "Инфа":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Информация по альбомам была взята из интернета.", parse_mode='html')
    elif message.text == "Музыка":
        audio = open('F:/10.mp3', 'rb')
        bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, audio)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ошибаешься", parse_mode='html')

bot.polling(none_stop=True) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать

```
while audio == None:
    audio = open('F:/10.mp3', 'rb')
```

А про текст из else не знаю

Answer (score 0):

я думаю боту нужно указать контент тип про аудио как минимум
@client.message_handler(content_types=['audio'])